# How can i mock AngularFirestore chained methods in jasmine?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore, jasmine, angularfire2

How can i mock angularfirestore and test the **placeOrder** method?

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {}

placeOrder(order: Order, restaurantId: string): Observable<void> {
   return from(this.afs.doc<Order(`restaurants/${restaurantId}/orders/${order.id}`)
                       .set(order, { merge: true }));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe:

```
    const AngularFirestoreStub = {
        doc: () => {
          return {
            set: () => {
              // I assume it is a promise because of `from`
              return Promise.resolve(/*... Data you want here */),
            }
          };
        }
    };
 ....
   let afs: any; // declare afs
 ....
    beforeEach(
        async(() => {
           TestBed.configureTestingModule({
               imports: [ RouterTestingModule],
               providers: [{provide: AngularFirestore, useValue: AngularFirestoreStub}]
               declarations: [ AppComponent ]
           }).compileComponents();
        })
    );

afs = TestBed.get(AngularFirestore); // if using Angular 9, this should be .inject instead of .get


it('calls doc with the correct route', async done => {
  // spy on calls to the fireStore.doc and call its actual implementation
  spyOn(afs, 'doc').and.callThrough();
  // call the method and await its response by converting the observable to a promise
  await component.placeOrder({ id: 1 }, 1).pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
  // expect fireStore.doc was called with the right argument
  expect(afs, 'doc').toHaveBeenCalledWith('restaurants/1/orders/1');
  done();
});
```

Check this out: [How to provide/mock Angularfirestore module inside angular component for default test to pass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48760093/how-to-provide-mock-angularfirestore-module-inside-angular-component-for-default)

Comment: How should i test it in the 'it' that the doc is called with, and the set is called with? I am getting Cannot read property 'set' of undefined error.

Comment: I would call `placeOrder` and see the observable it returned is indeed what `set` returns. If this previous statement is true, then for sure `doc` and `set` were called. As far as `Cannot read property set of undefined`, it could be it was mocked wrong. Check out the link I linked and work towards the goal bit by bit.

Comment: I would like to test also that in the doc was clled with the correct route (`restaurants/${restaurantId}/orders/${order.id}`). And could you extend your answer with the spec, how i should have the expect?

Comment: I have made an edit, something like that should get you going.